# Postgres queries running longer than statement_timeout

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `statement_timeout` set to `10000` (10 seconds) for a user in my Postgres database. However when I look at active queries in `pg_stat_activity` I find queries running for over 10 seconds (in some cases longer than 10 minutes). I set `statement_timeout` on the role executing these queries, and I have verified that in the `pg_user` table the user has `statement_timeout=10000` set.

These statements are all inserts and I've verified there are no ungranted locks.

Why are these queries not being killed after the timeout?

Comment: Did you reload your config? With pg_reload_conf() function or restarting your db?

Comment: Does "show statement_timeout" showing you the correct value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the issue is that the transactions are in the `idle` state (and since this is Postgres 10 I can further tell you the `wait_event` is `ClientRead`) and this means they are governed by a different timeout (although the documentation is ambiguous about this). The relevant config to set is `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`.